# Function returns NA while function builder returns proper answer

Tags: excel

I have the following table:

```
  |A | B
1 |1
2 |2
3 |3
```

So I simply have the numbers 1 to 3 in cells A1:A3.
I use the following formula:

```
=MATCH(1,((A1:A3=A2)*(A1:A3=A2)),0)
```

As you can guess, the second argument returns a table with {0,1,0} and so my function should return **2**. My cell prints #N/A while if I click the function builder, the proper answer is printed (2).

I have the same problem if I use
    =MATCH(TRUE,(A1:A3=A2),0)

Obviously my real application is much more complex, but this small bug makes the whole strategy falls down.
Source of the idea: http://www.exceltactics.com/vlookup-multiple-criteria-using-index-match/ . For him it seems to work perfectly

I'm using Excel 2013 on Windows 7 if this helps

---

edit: small correction in formulae

Comment: a) Don't you need a 2 in A4 for that result? b) Are you using CSE to finalize the formula?

Comment: Hi, you just made me discover "CSE" and it just saved my day. I wish I had a Matlab license though

Comment: to answer a) : I indeed wanted to write A2 and not A4

Comment: Please post a response, I'll accept it and it will close this topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `=MATCH(1,((A1:A3=A2)*(A1:A3=A2)),0)` formula is an **array formula**¹ and must be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd> (*aka* CSE) all struck together on the keyboard. If entered correctly, Excel with wrap the formula in braces (e.g. **{** and **}**). You do not type these in yourself.

---

¹ <sub>Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>. Once entered into the first cell correctly, they can be filled or copied down or right just like any other formula. Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum. See [Guidelines and examples of array formulas](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7d94a64e-3ff3-4686-9372-ecfd5caa57c7) for more information.</sub>